# angular issue with ng-model object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Model object is doesn't iterate by some reason. When i trying to loop of $scope.model it doesn't work... when i select few check-box i need checked ids in console..
$scope.model is there its dynamic. It is by default empty but if you check some checkboxs it will create.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hPn01mcxjzoHGSwMZQrW?p=preview

```
$scope.model = {}; 

  for(var i in $scope.model){
   console.log(i);
   if($scope.model[i]== true){
   console.log("checked id is"+i);
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed problem description including what you expect your code to do and what it is currently doing different than expectations. The demo doesn't even include the `for` loop shown in question

Comment: and also mention who will be triggering the above piece of code, since your plunker is working fine

Comment: looks like you are just missing a closing bracket in your for loop.....

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over the model when the model state changes? I think some details are missing from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added ng-click(key) function in your input element of html file.

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model[key]" ng-true-value="'{{val}}'" ng-click="selectedkey(key)" ng-false-value="undefined">
```

JS

```
$scope.selectedkey = function(key){
            console.log(key);
}
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3BgByGalRR5uxnNP7Fq?p=preview)

click on check box and check your browser's console.

Comment: Check Now I changed plunker URL.

Comment: can't we have solution using $watch for model object?